# Unique Solution for Square-root function on Matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis, matrix-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Prove that for every n by n matrix M sufficiently close to the identity matrix there exists a square-root matrix (solution of $A^2 = M$) and the solution is unique if $A$ is required to be sufficiently close to the identity matrix?

Okay so call the inverse of that function $f$, its derivative $df = (A+H)^2-A^2 -A^2 = AH+HA$. We know that A is sufficiently close to the identity and so is AH+HA. Well now to apply the Inverse function theorem we need df to invertible. Well now let's say we prove that $df$ is invertible (because A is sufficiently close to $I$ we know that $df$ is basically $2H$ and I saw somewhere that that is invertible but why?). Now we can apply the inverse function theorem and say that indeed there is a unique solution to $A^2=M$ if both are required to be sufficiently close to the identity matrix?

Compute the derivative of the square-root function $M\text{->}A$?

Show that the binomial expansion can be used to compute A?

Comment: How about the inverse function theorem instead?

Comment: you are correct I just made a dumb typo

Comment: No worries! Instead of considering the square root function, instead calculate the derivative of $A \mapsto A^2$ and see what happens around the identity.

Comment: what I understood from this I added to my original post, does this make sense and if so how can I move forward with proving df is invertible.

Comment: Since $df_I(H) = 2H$, we have a linear inverse given by $\frac{1}{2} H$. If you want to be extremely formal about it, note that $T_I(M_{n \times n}) \cong T_I(\mathbb{R}^{n^2}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. $f$ maps $I \mapsto I$. We have $df_I(H) = 2H$ as you stated. Looking at it as a map from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, this map is still multiplication by $2$ so the inverse is given by dividing by $2$. Now the inverse function theorem says there are small enough neighbourhoods where the function itself is invertible and you're done.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, so this then implies that the derivative of the square root function is just $\frac{1}{AH+HA}$?

Comment: Not exactly, that expression doesn't necessarily mean anything either. The inverse function theorem says $d_I(f^{-1}) = (df_I)^{-1}$, so the derivative of the inverse (which is the square root function) is exactly $\frac{1}{2} H $, as we showed earlier.